# How can I stream video with Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to streaming videos which uploaded with MultipartFile and saved video path to database. When I execute a get request to this method "http://localhost:8080/video/{id}" video is just downloading but not showing something, also I tried to watch video with html  but no action.

```
 public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getVideoById(Long id) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Video video = this.videoRepository.findById(id).get();
    
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(video.getFile().getUrl());
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    
    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(video.getFile().getContentType()));
    headers.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    headers.set("Expires", "0");
    headers.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    headers.set("Connection", "keep-alive");
    headers.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(fis), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know about *InputStreamResource* but I got this working long time ago with a ResponseEntity wrapping *byte[]*.
Try out returning a Response with these headers with *data* being a byte[] obtained by the video file:

```java
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .header("Content-Type", "video/"+ yourFileType)
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .header("Content-Length", yourContentLength)
                .header("Content-Range", "bytes " + rangeStart + "-" + 
                        rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize)
                .body(data);
```

Comment: I tried and just installing, thank you for answer I should look to spring webflux.

Comment: Webflux is great but is not a necessity for this to work generally. Maybe you could also share the frontend code you are using in the question?

Comment: I created a simple page just added a <video src="http://localhost:8080/video/39"> and didn't work. I execute a get request to your answer but just installed the video.

Comment: Do you use Chrome? Did you also try directly calling your endpoint with the browser? How does your endpoint look like (Annoations and Params)?

Comment: Yes I used chrome with directliy call, also I dont know what is the ranges. I find a tutorial https://github.com/saravanastar/video-streaming/ in here, I implemented ranges but now I dont know how can I write "Range" header

Comment: My endpoint localhost:8080/video/48 48 is pathParam calling with "id", also I added a RequestHeader value is Range but I dont know how can I use this header.

Comment: I used MultipartFileSender https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/d927d9b8cb9ea1268af74316cd20b7192ca92da7/src/main/java/lan/dk/podcastserver/utils/multipart/MultipartFileSender.java and its works